# Backbone.js event doubts

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

i have to create events using backbone.js.Below is my js code

```
var Trainee = Backbone.Model.extend();

            var TraineeColl = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                model: Trainee,
                url: 'name.json'
            });

            var TraineeView = Backbone.View.extend({
                el: "#area",




                template: _.template($('#areaTemplate').html()),

                render: function() {
                        this.model.each(function(good){
                        var areaTemplate = this.template(good.toJSON());
                        $('body').append(areaTemplate);
                    },this);

                    return this;
                }
            });

            var good = new TraineeColl();
            var traineeView = new TraineeView({model: good});
            good.fetch();


            good.bind('reset', function () {
            $('#myButtons').click(function() {
                traineeView.render();
                });
            });



<div class = "area"></div>
     <div class="button" id="myButtons">
<button class="firstbutton" id="newbutton">
   Display

</button>
</div>
    <script id="areaTemplate" type="text/template">
                 <div class="name">
                    <%= name %>
                </div>
                <div class="eid">
                    <%= eid %>
                </div>
                 <div class="subdomain">
                    <%= subdomain %>
                </div>
```

my o/p on clicking display button is
Display  // this is a button//

Sinduja 
E808514 
HPS

Shalini 
E808130 
HBS

Priya 
E808515 
HSG

Now from the view i have to bind a change event to the model..the changes in the model must be triggered on the view to display the output on the click of display button.

Comment: when a model changes do you want to display( on click on display button) all the models or just the changed model ?

Answer (score 1):

This isn´t exactly answering your queston but:

if trainee (I've renamed it to trainees) is a collection you should set it using:

```
new TraineeView({collection: trainees});
```

Then in render:

```
this.collection.models.each(function(trainee)
```

And you propably wan´t to move the call to fetch outside the view, in the router perhaps:

```
trainees = new TraineeColl();
view = new TraineeView({collection: trainees});
trainees.fetch();
```

That way your view only listens to the model.

You also should move the bind part to the views initialize method

```
this.collection.bind('reset', function () {
                      this.render();
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ya this is rite.But this is not my doubt i don use router in my script.Al i wanna know s how to bind a change event to model from view and the changes in model shd be triggered in view n den the result shd be displayed on a button click

Comment: I see you changed your initial question a bit but you could basically put the 'router code' in the click handler if you want. I´d consider adding a router though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var TraineeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   el: "#area",

   initialize : function(options){            // you will get the passed model in   
//options.model
       var trainee = new TraineeColl();
       trainee.fetch();
       trainee.bind('reset change', this.render,this); //change will trigger render
// whenever any model in the trainee collection changes or is modified

    }

    template: _.template($('#areaTemplate').html()),

    render: function() {
           this.model.each(function(trainee){
           var areaTemplate = this.template(trainee.toJSON());
           $('body').append(areaTemplate);
           },this);

         return this;
     }
 });

 var traineeView = new TraineeView({model: trainee});                
     });
```

Comment: now if my model is Trainee then shd i pass initialize : function(Trainee){...} is this d way..becos i tried the script tat u sent me but it doesnt work..

Comment: @user2082957 , you just do this in initialize : function(option){ console.log(JSON.stringify(option.model) } you will get trainee model

Comment: @user2082957 , a few comments , you have created very confusing names for models and collection , you model is Trainee , and then you instantiated  your collection as trainee , it get little confusing here

Comment: could you also elaborate on "then the o/p based on the changes shd be rendered on a button click." in your Q description

Comment: Now from the view i have to bind a change event to the model..the changes in the model must be triggered on the view to display the output on the click of display button.